# How to delete a folder with check-out

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am new to Sharepoint, i need to delete a folder, but it is not allowed because someone made a check-out on that folder.

The one who made the check-out is on vacation and the folder needs to be deleted.

How can i delete that folder?

To delete files i can follow this tutorial: http://moss-arvit.blogspot.com/2011/09/sharepoint-2010-file-is-currently.html

But to delete a folder i could not see how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're the owner of the SharePoint list or have some sort of administrative rights, you should be able to force them to check the folder in the same way you'd check-in a folder or file normally. Click the ellipsis (`...`) and find the `Check-in Document` or something along those lines. You'll be prompted to force the check-in. Select yes, you should now either have ownership of the check-in, or the folder should be checked in.

Your tutorial talks about items that have no checked in version. I outline it here in case your link dies:

If this is an item that hasn't been checked in before, then you'll have to go to the Library Settings and select `Manage Files which have no checked in version`. Then you'll see a list of items yet to be checked in, and you'll be able to take ownership of them.

[image]